# Java: Statements are not executing in order

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sleep

I am executing the following code:

```
    lnum.setVisible(false);
    Lsums.setVisible(false);
    Ldigits.setVisible(false);
    Lrows.setVisible(false);
    L1.setVisible(false);
    t1.setVisible(false);
    t2.setVisible(false);
    t3.setVisible(false);
    Button.setVisible(false);
    Done.setText("Done!");
    System.out.println("Done!");
    //setting everything invisible and printing Done on the screen
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    System.exit(0);
```

What should happen according to me: Done label is set to text "Done!" and then println followed by 5 seconds wait and then the program closes. But what is happening is; it does println and then waits for 5 secs but it never sets the done label to Done!
Why?

**Update 1**
Note if i just remove the sleep try and catch block, then it does the thing and then displays the done properly but does not if sleep blocks are present

**Update 2** Why does it not first output it and then sleep? Why?
[Like in the answers they said that it would hang, ok i get that but if i have written that it should set label it should set it and then pause after setting it why before???]

If it is still unclear: See what i want to do is, 1. make some items invisible 2. change the label's text 3. wait for 5 seconds 4. exit automatically
In this exact order.

Comment: `Done` is what here? show us your full code?

Comment: can we see the Done object?

Comment: In which thread do you execute this code? Is it EDT thread?

Comment: You cannot `sleep` on the `Event Dispatch Thread`. Your code will freeze the UI.

Comment: I think you have to redraw the frame.

Comment: @G.S I concluded that the label is not set as earlier it was "" and from this i changed it to "Done!" but it does not appear

Comment: @Esq Done is just a JLabel

Comment: @ExtremeCoders But it should freeze it after setting right? Why not?

Comment: @DakshShah for the Upd2. You just changed model of the label. It means swing will use new model state(new text) when paint lable next time.

Comment: unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sleep in the Event Dispatch Thread(EDT) you freeze your UI and Swing cannot refresh the label caption. In this case you just changed model of the label. It means swing will use new model state(new text) when paint lable next time. And when you freeze this thread and exit app, you do not give any chance to repaint label with new text.

EDT - is a special thread where all components draw on the screen. When you invoke `Thread#sleep()` you blocks EDT and swing cannot redraw your Label. After sleep finished you exit from process and Swing cannot repaint new text.

Just try to remove `System.exit()` invocation.

If you want to exit you app after 5 seconds when label changed you can shedule `System#exit()` call in the separate Thread. Like in any multythreading environment you cannot wait exactly 5 sec, you just can advice OS scheduler to perform action in around 5 sec. It will depends from CPU load on CPU. But in normal env it should emulate some pause when label changed

Consider following code(it is not production level, but should work):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { //create new thread
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000); //wait here
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.exit(0); //kill Java process
    }
}).start(); //start new thread
//EDT thread should continue executing
```

Comment: can you please tell how exactly should the code be?

Comment: So how else would i exit my program? I want it to exit :P

Comment: @DakshShah so do you want to change UI state and close program programmatically?

Comment: Yah but after the the label text changes, i want to wait for 5 seconds

Comment: @DakshShah like in any multythreading environment you cannot wait exactly 5 sec, you just can advice OS scheduler to perform action in around 5 sec. It will depends from CPU load on CPU. But in normal env it should emulate some pause when label changed.

Comment: What do you mean by if not in production level

Comment: @DakshShah review the code snippet from the answer. Ask if you want to clarify something.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Done.setText("Done!");
    try {
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       System.out.println("Done!");
   } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }
   System.exit(0);
```